# PHPMailer error: Could not instantiate mail function

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I've looked through all the old posts on stackoverflow and many on other websites and find lots of posts with the same error, but none of the fixes work.

The following is the error I get:

> Mailer Error: Could not instantiate mail function.

Is there something missing or incorrect?

```
<?php
require '../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->Host     = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "censored@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "censored";

$mail->setFrom('censored@gmail.com');
$mail->addReplyTo('censored@gmail.com');
$mail->addAddress('censored@gmail.com');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer mail() test';
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));

$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what you're missing.

You need to set these 2 things to get it to work properly:

```
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```

Comment: I have the same issue on a new server. Same code on old server worked. I added the 

$mail->isSMTP();

and now the error is:

SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. ....Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host